# Fulton, an introduction to algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the first chapter there is a question:

> Let k be and infinite field, $F \in k[X_1,...,X_n]$. Suppose $F(a_1,...a_n) = 0$ for all $a_1,...,a_n$. Show that $F=0$.

If a multivariable polynomial yields zero for every possible input value combination, doens't that mean it is zero polynomial? What should be proven here?

Comment: Right, then its the zero polynomial.

Comment: You're forgetting that a polynomial is different from a polynomial function.

Comment: Take $k=\Bbb F_2$ and $F=x(x-1)$ and you'll understand what needs to be proven here.